# Periodic Read from AWS S3 and publish to SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, scheduled-tasks, amazon-sqs

I have an S3 bucket with different files. I need to read those files and publish SQS msg for each row in the file. 
I cannot use S3 events as the files need to be processed with a delay - put to SQS after a month.

I can write a scheduler to do this task, read and publish. But can I was AWS for this purpose?
AWS Batch or AWS data pipeline or Lambda.?

I need to pass the date(filename) of the data to be read and published.

Edit : The data volume to be dealt is huge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the core, you need to do two things:

Enumerate all of the object in a bucket in S3, and perform some action on any object uploaded more than a month ago.

Can you use Lambda or Batch to do this?  Sure.  A Lambda could be set to trigger once a day, enumerate the files, and post the results to SQS.

Should you?  No clue.  A lot depends on your scale, and what you plan to do if it takes a long time to perform this work.  If your S3 bucket has hundreds of objects, it won't be a problem.  If it has billions, your Lambda will need to be able to handle being interrupted, and continuing paging through files from a previous run.

Alternatively, you could use S3 events to trigger a simple Lambda that adds a row to a database.  Then, again, some Lambda could run on a cron job that asks the database for old rows, and publishes that set to SQS for others to consume.  That's slightly cleaner, maybe, and can handle scaling up to pretty big bucket sizes.

Or, you could do the paging through files, deciding what to do, and processing old files all on a t2.micro if you just need to do some simple work to a few dozen files every day.

It all depends on your workload and needs.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two ways to do this entirely using AWS serverless offerings without even having to write a scheduler.

You could use [S3 events to start a Step Function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-cloudwatch-events-s3.html) that [waits for a month](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-wait-state.html) before reading the S3 file and [sending messages through SQS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-sqs.html).

With a little more work, you could [use S3 events to trigger a Lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html) which writes the messages to DynamoDB with [a TTL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/TTL.html) of one month in the future.  When the TTL expires, you can have another Lambda that listens to the DynamoDB streams, and when there’s a delete event, it publishes the message to SQS. (A good introduction to this general strategy can be found [here](https://medium.com/swlh/scheduling-irregular-aws-lambda-executions-through-dynamodb-ttl-attributes-acd397dfbad9).)

While the second strategy might require more effort, you might find it less expensive than using Step Functions depending on the overall message throughput and whether or not the S3 uploads occur in bursts or in a smooth distribution.

Comment: I liked the solution, using S3 -> DynamoDB (TTL) -> DynamoDB stream -> we have events that need to be processed. To augment further, the user can delete Object from S3, it implies we need to delete corresponding item from DynamoDB. And so it'd create entry in DynamoDB stream. Hence, to distinguish such record from DynamoDB stream, "principalId" can help. As when it's deleted because of TTL,  "principalId" is "dynamodb.amazonaws.com", else, it is value of user account that is used to delete item. Ref- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/time-to-live-ttl-streams.html

Comment: As the data volume is huge, I cant have as many open Step functions. DynamoDB events solutions seems a great solution, but then again weighing it to any scheduled read from S3 and write SQS direct way would be cheaper here.